# Who are the people in the newspaper?

Tags: reference, dc-extended-universe, justice-league

[image]

Who are the people on left and right side of superman? The headline says Do they return to their planet?

So they could be aliens, Is the first one is The Mask?? He looks like him. I am not a comic book fan, so if it is Mask, then he and Superman are in same universe? If not who is he? and the girl right to superman?

Any reference to future movies?